# Submitting form through console

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, contact-form

I want to test my server for spamming so I want to send 10 mails through my contact form.

But I have a contact form that reloads after it is sent. How do I need to do this?

Tried with Chrome Developer Tools to inject with;

So I go to `http://localhost:8080/index#contact`, open up Developer Tools and write

```
$("input[name='Name']").val(":)")
$("input[name='Contact']").val(":)")
$("textarea[name='Msg']").val(":)")

$(".form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("Submit is triggered")
})
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    $(".form").submit()
}
```

But I don't get any mails. How can I test it with the Developer Tools?

Comment: You are preventing default form behaviour, that's why it does not work. Use cURL / any other HTTP client better.

Comment: @moonwave99, I tried somethings with cURL but it's not doing wat I want still reloading it.